Retrieving results from finished multiprocessing task as it has finished
I need to run dozens of computationally intensive CPU-bound parallel tasks. Currently I do it using joblib delayed and Parallel:
resultTuples = Parallel(n_jobs=-1, prefer="processes")(delayed(RunSingleTask)(*p) for p in run_params)

It works fine but I have to wait until all tasks have finished to get the list of results and process them after. And I'd like to get the result of each finished task right after it is ready to process it.
Tasks have no IO, so I don't see any purpose in using async stuff like:
for first_completed in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
   ...

So how can I do this?

You can use multiprocessing.pool.Pool which has methods imap and imap_unordered.

Is there any real difference with proposed answer i.e. using ProcessPoolExecutor?

No, they are very similar. multiprocessing.pool is just older.

You can use ProcessPoolExecutor() and as_completed():
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed


def _sum(a, b):
    return a + b


if __name__ == '__main__':
    inputs = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)]

    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        fts = [executor.submit(_sum, a, b) for a, b in inputs]

        for f in as_completed(fts):
            print(f.result())


Prints
3
7
11
15
19


Is there any particular difference between ProcessPoolExecutor and Parallel under the hood? Or does it do basically the same?

@shda ProcessPoolExecutor() (from the standard library) and Parallel() both parallelize the execution of tasks, they are similar and differ in their flexibility and error-handling, etc. For most standard parallel processing tasks, ProcessPoolExecutor() is sufficient and convenient to use. For complex scenarios, you can use Parallel().
